# Issue scrolling Div in sencha touch

Tags: html, extjs, scroll

I am working in sencha touch. I am facing an issue i.e. I have a panel on my screen in which I have a div which  dynamically appends. It takes an image taken by Camera, the issue is that I am trying to scroll the panel but couldn't

My code is :

```
{
   xtype:'panel',
   id:'picPanel',
   scroll:true, //but it doesn't work ,
   scrollable:true, // But it is not working too
   scrollable:'vertical', // Not working too 
   style:'width:112%;margin:-15px; padding:0px; margin-top:-20px;padding-right:-15px',
   html:'<div id="pic"> </div>',
}
```

I have tried to give the property to div as well

```
overflow:scroll; // Not working
```

CSS:

```
#pic {
   margin-top:-48px;
   padding-left:3px;
}
```

Comment: Please no more editing and try to answer. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock: true
}
```

Comment: Funny think it works OK in the browser but doesn't work on the native app :(

Comment: I have the same issue, that is because the native app uses a webview from the default browser, it does not use the chrome browser